# Get files from folder based on conditions mvc asp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, download

I have two tables, Note and file(one to many).
I saved all files in "Files" folder,then i saved name,path,extension in File tables in addition to NoteID(FK).

I uploaded them successfully.
But when i want to download files based on NoteID condtions, i can't.
i can get all files in that folder.

My question is How i can get some files from specific folder based on condition?
i have tried several solutions, but they don't work.

Any help?

Action:

```
public ActionResult Download(int NoteID)
{

    var fs = db.Files.Where(f => f.NoteID == NoteID);

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Files"));


    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
    }
    ViewBag.Files = files;
    return View();
}

public FileResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
{
    var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Files/"), fileName);
    return File(filepath, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath), fileName);
}
```

Download View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Download Files";
    var Files = (ViewBag.Files as string[]);

    if (Files != null && Files.Any())
    {
        foreach (var file in Files)
        {
            <br />
            @Html.ActionLink(file, "DownloadFile", new { fileName = file })
            <br />

        }
    }
    else
    {
        <label>No File(s) to Download</label>
    }
}
```

Edit:

the code above is working and get and display all files in 'Files' folder

when i'm trying run code below i get IOEception

actions:

```
  public ActionResult Download(int? NoteID)
    {


        var fs = db.Files.Where(f => f.NoteID == NoteID);


        string[] files = new string[(fs.Count()) - 1];



        int counter = 0;

        foreach (var item in fs)
        {
            files[counter] = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Files/"+item.FileName)).Single();
            /*here is the Exception
             * 
            System.IO.IOException:
            { "The directory name is invalid.\r\n"}

            InnerException message:
            The directory name is invalid.    
            */

        }



        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
        }
        ViewBag.Files = files;
        return View();
    }

    public FileResult DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {
        var filepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/Files/"), fileName);
        return File(filepath, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filepath), fileName);
    }
```

View:

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Download Files";
    var Files = (ViewBag.Files as string[]);

    if (Files != null && Files.Any())
    {
        foreach (var file in Files)
        {
            <br />
            @Html.ActionLink(file, "DownloadFile", new { fileName = file })
            <br />

        }
    }
    else
    {
        <label>No File(s) to Download</label>
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give some explanation where you receiving exception?

Comment: System.IO.IOException:
{ "The directory name is invalid.\r\n"}
 InnerException message:
                The directory name is invalid.

Comment: In your action DownloadFile() did you verify which value has `filepath`? Because you have that exception it means that you have problem to locate file. Right?

Comment: @kat1330 Actually, the compiler stopped before call DownloadFile action, do you know method that accept file path as parameter and retrieve that file. because i want to store it in array of string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your new code:

```
files[counter] = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Files/"+item.FileName))
```

You are using an incorrect parameter. You are passing a file path, but this method needs a directory path.

You can use this:

```
var filteredByFilename = Directory
                        .GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/Files"))
                        .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f))
                        .Where(f => f.StartsWith("yourFilename"));

ViewBag.Files = filteredByFilename.ToArray();
```

But in your case I think is better to use Directory.EnumerateFiles method. Please read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

So the new code would be:

```
var filteredByFilename = Directory
                        .EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("/Files"))
                        .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f))
                        .Where(f => f.StartsWith("yourFilename"));

ViewBag.Files = filteredByFilename.ToArray();
```

The whole Download method could be:

```
public ActionResult Download(int NoteID)
{
    var fs = db.Files.Where(f => f.NoteID == NoteID);

    var fileNames = Directory
        .EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("/Files"))
        .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));

    var result = new List<string>();

    foreach (var fileName in fs)
    {
        var filteredByName = fileNames.Where(f => f.StartsWith(fileName));
        result.AddRange(filteredByName);
    }

    ViewBag.Files = result.ToArray();
    return View(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the proper method for my case? I mean what is method that retrieve file when i pass file path?

Comment: It works, but unfortunately it retrieve only one file. how i can add the rest of files, because i change last line of your code: .Where(f => f.StartsWith(fs.Single().FileName)); i tried to add them in foreach loop but 'filteredByFilename '  IEnumerable<string> and it does not accept adding new item. Any help?

Comment: I edited my answer and I added the whole method. Can you try it and tell me if it works?